# jQuery v2 showing as potentially suspicious

Tags: javascript, jquery, malware, malware-detection, jquery-2.0

We have had an alert in Google webmaster tools saying there was a malware issue on our site, however it didn't provide any example urls and has since been reviewed and cleared. Trying to do some digging as to why this occurred using an online scanner (http://scanner.pcrisk.com/) it has flagged jquery-2.1.4.min.js as being potentially suspicious.

The details I got from the scanner were as follows:

> /styleassets/javascript/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
>   Reason:
>   Detected potentially suspicious content.

Details:

```
Detected potentially suspicious initialization of function pointer to JavaScript 
method eval <code> = eval; <code/>
```

I can't be sure if this was causing the issue but want to try and find out more. I've had a search and haven't found anything directly related to why it would be flagged.

Does any know if this is an issue or has anyone found similar with a version of jQuery?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/potentially-suspicious-files

Comment: Hi, Is it just down to it being minified that's causing it to flag the file as suspicious?